# Canvas не отображает картинку

Tags: javascript

Я писал браузерную игру. Но canvas не отображает картинку. Проверил ошибок нет. Но видно что что-то не корректно.
Помогите найти ошибку.
Вот программный код:

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

/**
 * **********************************
 * LOADING GAME RESOURCES
 * **********************************
 */

//loading images
var bird = new Image();
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeUp = new Image();
var pipeBottom = new Image();

bird.src = "./img/bird.png";
bg.src = "./img/bg.png";
fg.src = "./img/fg.png";
pipeUp.src = "./img/pipeUp.png";
pipeBottom.src = "./img/pipeBottom.png";

/**
 * **********************************
 * CODE
 * **********************************
 */
// draw function
function draw() {
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
}
pipeBottom.onload = draw();
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

var bird = new Image(); 
var bg = new Image();
var fg = new Image();
var pipeUp = new Image();
var pipeBottom = new Image();

bird.src = "https://img.icons8.com/external-wanicon-lineal-color-wanicon/128/external-bird-nature-wanicon-lineal-color-wanicon.png";

bg.src = "./img/bg.png";
fg.src = "./img/fg.png";
pipeUp.src = "./img/pipeUp.png";
pipeBottom.src = "./img/pipeBottom.png";

function draw() {
  // Последние 2 значения отвечает за размер изображения Размер изображения
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 80, 80);
}

bird.onload = draw;
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

canvas {
  box-shadow: 0 0 12px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400" id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Ничего не произошло. Картинка всё ещё не отображается.